# Why are there no function pointers in Java?

Tags: java, functions

Lately I started studying about different interesting concepts that exist in languages other than Java. Since the only language I've ever programmed with is Java, a lot of these concepts are very new to me. So this question may be very naive :) .

I learned recently about first class functions and function pointers. Why are there no function pointers in Java? Or at least some variation of them, like delegates in C#?

Maybe it's just the excitement of learning about this concept, but it seems to me like it could be a powerful feature in the language.

Comment: FYI, Java does now support lambda functions (I think only as of Java 8). I'm not sure if there are plans to add function pointers or delegates in the future.

Comment: James Gosling probably figured you wouldn't mind typing 5 lines of code to create an anonymous class. As @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner points out, Java 8 now has lambda expressions and "method expressions" which are essentially a way to use methods as first-class functions. If you *really* want to play around with first-class functions, you should look into functional programming languages like Standard ML.

Comment: All questions of the form "Why did they not put [some feature] in [some language]" always have the same answer: the benefit did not outweigh the cost.  Consider the philosophy that the designers of Java had; it was supposed to be the kinder, gentler, safer version of C++.  Pointers don't really fit that philosophy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What if they had put it in? Would that mean the benefit was higher, the cost was lower, or they just didn't care about that ratio? I'm just asking, because function (or method) pointers are not such a rare thing in other languages. So it either must be really hard to integrate into Java or someone thought that next to nobody will ever use them.

Comment: In short, they are unsafe, and Java is supposed to be a safe language.  http://www.coderanch.com/t/370799/java/java/java-pointer-concept

Comment: @RobertHarvey Function pointers, even the untamed C version, are very much unlike ordinary C pointers. You can't reasonably do arithmetic on them (I don't know if it's outright illegal in C, but even if it's allowed it serves no purpose and can safely be removed), and lifetime issues such as use-after-free are not possible because functions life forever.

Comment: Sure you can do arithmetic on them.  You might even want to if you have an array of them.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Arithmetic on function pointers means: Given `fp` being a function pointer, do `fp + 1` or such and get another (valid) function pointer. When you use a (C-style) array of function pointers, you do pointer arithmetic *on the pointer to the first element of that array*, which is an ordinary pointer-to-T (for `T` = some function pointer). The former is not possible (function layout in memory is not specified, you can't even get the "size" of a function); the latter is possible and useful but does not involve pointer arithmetic *on function pointers*.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, every question of the form "Why didn't they do X?" can have an answer of the form "the benefit did not outweigh the cost", but that doesn't say anything more than "they thought it was better not to".  Of course they thought their course of action was the right one, otherwise they would have done something different.  Just because a glib and uninformative answer exists doesn't mean that a good answer does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelShaw to go deeper than that is often a matter of searching for the design documents, articles from the author, and guesses as to what the designers were thinking and where they drew inspiration from. We can rationalize some of those ourselves, but much of the rest of is guessing about someone else's thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelShaw The question of "why does Java not have feature X" (and there are *many* Xs) can be better done by searching and interviewing the appropriate people rather than trying to draw on people's opinions who weren't part of the design process to rationalize and guess. A good answer *might* exist, but that doesn't make it a good question in the Stack Exchange format. To that extent, Robert's answer of "because the costs outweighed the benefits" is the simplest correct answer without doing legwork - legwork that anyone can do (it doesn't draw on our expert knowledge).

Comment: @MichaelT: I think it's taking the question too literally to assume that only the designer's secret thoughts could answer the question.  If you look at the two answers, they address features in Java that are more-or-less similar and the general avoidance of pointers in Java -- these are factual matters, not guesses about other people's thoughts.  I don't see what "the simplest correct answer without doing legwork" has to do with anything.

Answer (score 4):

Function pointers by themselves are more or less a workaround for the lack of first-class functions. But Java *does* have first-class functions as of Java 8 (lambdas), and it had was of (somewhat) easily faking them since Java 1.1 (anonymous inner classes).

But actually, Java (or more precisely the JRE) also has a concept that more directly corresponds to function pointers than lambdas or anonymous inner classes: [`MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html)s. It's a handle for a method. Which is really not much different than a pointer to a function. They were added in Java SE 7.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: because Java has other ways to accomplish the same thing, and the language goes out of its way to hide pointers behind references which do not have pointer semantics.

Long answer:

The primary benefit of a function pointer in C or C++ is for an external library to plug in functionality at runtime, because a class is not known at compile time. Consider a `WidgetFactory` in an application. It is extensible: one may subclass it to produce new widget types. However, it is not possible for a C++ application to create a `PluginWidgetFactory` because it has not been written yet.

Enter function pointers: after loading a DLL/SO file dynamically, that library will call a function in the main application and *register* itself as a factory. It will provide a function pointer to say "call this function and I will return my subclass of `WidgetFactory` that your compiler knew nothing about."

In Java, you would use reflection. The Java `WidgetFactory` would check a system property with the class name, and load the `PluginWidgetFactory` dynamically using reflection.

While Java does not support function pointers, it can accomplish the same end goal using different mechanisms. The creators of Java felt these other ways were better due to their goal of hiding pointers.